# Masturbation for 16 year old teenager

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

I'm 16 year old boy I sometimes masturbate because of my sexual urges or sexual desires I know it's haraam but I can't get married at the age of 16 and I can't fast for 365 days so is it permissible in that sense

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: I deleted the text because I'm not sure if my advice was good. Part of my answer was probably written without knowledge.

Comment: I have faith in allah and I pray namaz 5 times and read quran but I can't fast every weak because I'm a tennis player and I play tennis for 4 hours so I have to take proper diet otherwise I can get week that's why I'm asking this question is it permissible in this situation

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not. you should fast only one day in a week. And avoid to see the sexual thing. if you control your eyes than it's easy to escape the masturbation.

Comment: questionmark123
25●5
I have faith in allah and I pray namaz 5 times and read quran but I can't fast every weak because I'm a tennis player and I play tennis for 4 hours so I have to take proper diet otherwise I can get week that's why I'm asking this question is it permissible in this situation